# how to create a checkbox with the same value on vue .js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox

how do I make one of the check boxes true does not all go true, this is how the checkbox has the same value, if I am true all of them do not follow true
its myCode

```
 <section id="app">
<table>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" true-value="1" false-value="0" v-model="ai"></td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" true-value="1" false-value="0" v-model="ai"></td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" true-value="1" false-value="0" v-model="ai"></td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" true-value="1" false-value="0" v-model="ai"></td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" true-value="1" false-value="0" v-model="ai"></td>
    <td>{{ai}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
   const app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
    data: {
          ai: ''
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? I don't get what you are asking for?

Comment: Currently all of the checkboxes share the same value. What functionality do you actually require?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `ai: ''` to `ai: []`

From

```
data: {
  ai: ''
}
```

to

```
data: {
  ai: []
}
```

You can see the example in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox),